# How to capture group if it have comma inside double quotes in regex?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, capture-group

i'm new to this regex matching and have sample input like below.,

```
1,2,Name,"12,3"
1,2,Name,12
```

Now i need single regex to split both lines that like below capture groups..,

```
input.1->1
input.2->2
input.3->Name
input.4->"12,3"

input.1->1
input.2->2
input.3->Name
input.4->12
```

i have find regex and use it in ExtractTextProcessor like this.,

```
(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+)
```

It matches like below..,

```
input.1->1,2
input.2->Name
input.3->"12
input.4->3"
```

And stop me if anything i'm doing wrong

Please anyone guide me to resolve this.,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Should Work.

```
(\d+),(\d+),(\w+),(\d+$|(?:\"*\d*,*)*)
```

Input:

```
1,2,Name,"12,3"
1,2,Name,12
```

Output:

```
#1
$1 = 1
$2 = 2
$3 = Name
$4 = "12,3"

#2
$1 = 1
$2 = 2
$3 = Name
$4 = 12
```

Comment: is this possible without give \w,\d only use (.*)